# how to save generated document in csv in a folder

Tags: php

**I generate a document in csv format with php Spreadsheet**

[image]

**How do I save the document in the folder called save?**

[image: file save]

mi code

```
$header = [array("Name", "Age", "
direction", "
profession", "Total", "Asistencia", "Horas ];
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->fromArray($header, NULL, 'A1')
        ->fromArray($reporteCoach, NULL, 'A2'); 

$writer = new Csv($spreadsheet);
        $writer->save("myarchive.csv");
```

Comment: Provide the full path name in the call to the `save()` method.

Comment: when I put the route it shows me an error `$writer = new Csv($spreadsheet);
  $writer->save('/save/myarchive.csv');` 
don't save it in the folder 
please help me

Comment: @josedejesus Path starting with `/` means starting from root folder. Use `__DIR__ . '/save/myarchive.csv'`, just adjust path to actually reflect correct path to desired file

Comment: when I put `$writer->save(__DIR__ . '/save/myarchive.csv'); I don't save it in the folder` :,(

Comment: `__DIR__` resolves to the directory of the current file, which is probably in a subdir, so you likely need something like `$writer->save(__DIR__ . '/../save/myarchive.csv');` with one or more double dots to go back up. (Or use the fully qualified path from root.)

Comment: try placing all the recommendations but it does not store it in the folder.
Do you think the problem is that it does not get the folder, is it because I am using .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

can fix the problem, the error was because it was not directing the route correctly, those who are working with MVC and .htacces.

I recommend that you echo the path  to know which address in the folder you are directing them to.

```
echo <?=base_url?>;
echo base_url;
```

my case it was in the controller folder and it was where i put the save folder